# How to get raw Github URL for a large file

Tags: url, github

I am trying to host a UCSC Genome Browser hub from GitHub. I followed all the instructions at the link pasted below.

One of the instructions is to provide a you provide a raw.githubusercontent.com URL for each file. I can obtain this easily for text file in my repository but how do I get it for large files (around 40-50MB) that cannot be visualized in GitHub?

In the following link, it shows you where to click (the "Raw" button) to get the URL but you don't have that option for large binary files.. (they are bigwig files). How can I get the raw URL for these files?

https://genome.ucsc.edu/goldenPath/help/hgTrackHubHelp.html#Hosting

Thanks